# UNIX shell script while loop

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to write a script to track the progress of file change.

I have the following till now:

```
#!/bin/sh
old=‘ls -l /tmp/file‘
new=‘ls -l /tmp/file‘
while [ "$old" = "$new" ]
do
    new=‘ls -l /tmp/file‘
done
echo "The file has been changed"
```

The above program when run gives the message:

```
new: command not found
```

Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: You'd probably want `"$old" -eq "$new"`

Comment: @Marc, no, in the shell `=` is string comparison and `-eq` is numeric comparison.

Comment: @Mike, You might want to throw a `sleep 5` into your while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have space around `=`.

In shell, when you assign the values you cannot put space around `=`:

```
MY_VAR = "my value"  # this is wrong!
```

Shell will think: "call MY_VAR with arguments: ('=', 'my value') ", but wait! I don't know the command "MY_VAR"!

You need to do it this way:

```
MY_VAR="my value"  # this is OK!
```

BTW, consider using `inotifywatch` command. Here's example:

```
inotifywatch -v -e access -e modify -t 60 -r /file/to/watch
```